# Multipeer connectivity error change state : 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, connectivity

I am creating an iOS app that uses remote control functionality via the  Multipeer Connectivity Framework. Since the device to be connect to another iOS device,but throw error and So why is it trying to use the framework? And why is it failing after accepting the invitation and change state:0? Could it just be a bug in the Xcode 8 / Objective-C /iOS 10.

```
[ViceroyTrace] [ICE][ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id and change state : 0
```